# Unable to read Java object from response in Jersey 2

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I'm migrating my existing Jersey 1.x code to 2.x and I'm facing issue when executing the below code.

Jersey code:

```
      public String getEmployeeDetail(long empId) {
        String empName = null;
        String url = String.format("%s/%d/", "http://localhost:8080/emp/detail", empId);
        UriBuilder builder = UriBuilder.fromUri(url);
        WebTarget webtarget = client.target(builder.build());
        EmployeeDetail empDetail = webtarget.request("application/x-java-serialized-object").header("Cache-Control", "no-cache").get(EmployeeDetail.class);
        if(empDetail.getName() != null) {
          empName = empDetail.getName();
        }
        return empName;
      }
```

EmployeeDetail class:

```
      @XmlRootElement(name="employeeDetail")
      public class EmployeeDetail {
        String name;
        String age;
        public String getName() {
          return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
          this.name = name;
        }
        public String getAge() {
          return age;
        }
        public void setAge(String age) {
          this.age = age;
        }
      }
```

Exception:

```
    org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyReader not found for media type=application/x-java-serialized-object;class=com.client.response.EmployeeDetail, 
    type=class com.client.response.EmployeeDetail, genericType=class com.client.response.EmployeeDetail.
```

After some research , tried the following and it resulted the same error.

```
    Response response = webtarget.request("application/x-java-serialized-object").header("Cache-Control", "no-cache").get();
    System.out.println("response.getStatus()==>>" + response.getStatus());   output =============>>> 200
    EmployeeDetail empDetail = response.readEntity(new GenericType<EmployeeDetail>(){});
```

Comment: Why are we using `application/x-java-serialized-object`? If that's what you really want, then you need to write a MessageBodyReader to handle that media type.

Comment: In my previous jersey 1.x code, it was mentioned as "application/x-java-serialized-object" and it was working fine. hence i used the same here. if it is wrong , please tell what Im supposed to put ?

Comment: What does your web service actually return, it's not XML or JSON?

Comment: Not sure if it helps but I ran across this similar question reguarding Jersey?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15074431/how-do-i-make-jersey-use-java-serialization

Comment: After you get the answer from the linked duplicate, do `(client or webTarget).register(TheProvider.class)`. Probably best to just register it with the client

Comment: @Nicholas Smith My web service should return a pojo. (ex:EmployeeDetail,class). and even after registering the EmployeeDetail,class to the client and webTarget, still it didnt work

Comment: Got it worked !... Problem is that I missed to add the MessageBodyReader class to the client. It worked after adding it to the client.  MessageBodyReader class for serializing EmployeeDetails => EmployeeDetailReader.class.                                                      client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().hostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
        @Override
        public boolean verify(String s, SSLSession sslSession) {
          return true;
        }
      }).sslContext(sc).register(EmployeeDetailReader.class).build();